# What is the global "Request" object that is available on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, fetch-api

There is a global JavaScript object called "Request" on Chrome (51.0.2704.103) and Firefox (47.0).

Anyone knows what it is?

Comment: This is a very poor question... A basic search on MDN or any search engine would give you the result.

Comment: @Marco actually I could not easily find the answer on a search engine. Since this is quite a new feature, I thought some people might also be interested in the answer. At least it'll be easier to find the answer in a search engine now ;)

Comment: If you search for "Request" on MDN, it's the first result: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=request. If you search for "mdn request" on Google, it's the first result.

Comment: It's the first result on Google also if you search for "request object javascript" :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer while typing the question...

> The Request interface of the Fetch API represents a resource request.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request